# Integrating indefinite and improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I am given the integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^4(x)}{x^2}dx$$ And I must compute it. I know that the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$, but I don't really know how to begin solving this.

I am thinking of taking $f(x)=\frac{\sin^4(x)}{x^2}$ and then trying to find its antiderivative and evaluating it at the required limits, but I'm unsure of how to find the antiderivative of such a function.

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts leads to:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^4 x}{x^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{4\cos x\sin^3 x}{x}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(4x)}{x}\,dx $$
so we just need to exploit:
$$ \forall \alpha > 0,\quad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2} $$
to prove the claim.

Comment: Sorry...can you explain how this integration by parts is happening? I'm not seeing this in the form of the traditional $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$

Comment: $v=-1/x$ and $u=\sin^4 x$ is the answer to your question.